# Nodejs event is being emitted multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created my module **modulemy** with the following code :

```
var request = require('request');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var User = new EventEmitter();
var userFbInfos = new EventEmitter();

//database and calls the get started conversation.
User['checkUserRegistered'] =  function (userID) {
    //if registered and have phone number then nothing to do otherwise, get user infos return it  and last ask his phonenumber
    //Now we consider that the user is not registered. So we get is infos
    userFbInfos.getInfos(userID);
    userFbInfos.on('gotten', function (err, userInfos) {
        User.emit('checked',err, userInfos);
    });

}

//This gets user info from Facebook and notifies when the information is gotten via event gotten
//The thing is as node is event driven if you request the user info and run a code before getting that info, the userinfos will be null.

userFbInfos['getInfos'] = function (userID) {
    request.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/" + userID + "?fields=first_name,last_name,locale,gender,timezone,profile_pic&access_token=" + process.env.page_token,
    function (err, response, body) {
        userFbInfos.emit('gotten',err,JSON.parse(body));
    });
}

exports.userFbInfos = userFbInfos;
exports.User = User;
```

and then in my **app.js**, I am using it as follow :

```
modulemy = require('./modulemy.js');
                        var user = modulemy.User;
                        //Checking if user is registered.
                        user.checkUserRegistered('123');
                        //This variable checks if the event was trigger before already to not execute the code twice.
                        var called = false;
                        user.on('checked', function (err, userInfos) {

                            if (!called){
                                console.log("Call Checked");
                                var name = "";
                                if (typeof (userInfos) != 'undefined') {
                                    name = userInfos['first_name'];
                                }
                               console.log("Yes you are there");
                                called = true;
                            }
                        });
```

The problem is the checked event is being triggered multiple times... I don't understand where the problem is ... I need help.

Comment: In how many places are you requiring the `modulemy` module?

Comment: I copied the code and ran it and it worked as expected. I think perhaps @Sergeon may be along the right lines

Comment: I'd highly suggest you take a look at promises. This is not a good use of EventEmitter.

Comment: We need to see more code context, but often the appearance of receiving duplicate messages is not actually duplicate messages being received, but rather because you have duplicate event handlers that are each getting called on the same message.  I see multiple places where you set some message handler `xxx.on()` in a function. If that code is ever called more than once without removing the prior event handler, it will cause a duplicate event handler.

Comment: I only require the modulemy in on place and as you can see there is no place where I added more than on handler.

Answer (score 2):

there might be an issue when receiving the packages from fb. Try to count some variable up if the input data coming from the query is the same as the one from the query before.